# Data binding in ListBox on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm new to Windows Phone 8. I have a list of data from a server in this form:

```
RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(await serverData);

  mylist.ItemsSource = json.friends;
public class Friend
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string place { get; set; }
    public string going { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
}

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Friend> friends { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to display that data in a `ListBox` in the UI:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="mylist" Margin="10,0,30,0" Height="486" Width="404" FontSize="20">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,8">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding first_name }" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding last_name }" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding place }" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding going }" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding thumbnail }" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

that is a working version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` on the `ListBox` should be bound to `friends`, like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding friends}"  Margin="10,0,30,0" Height="486" Width="404" FontSize="20">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,8">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding first_name }" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding first_name }" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And also if you haven't done it already, you need to set the DataContext for the page after you downloaded the data, like this (assuming you do the downloading in the code-behind file of a page, e.g. MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(await serverData);
this.DataContext = json;
```

Comment: it works fine with me when i add to my code x:Name="mylist" and  mylist.ItemsSource = json.friends; do not know why but it work

Comment: Did you set the `this.DataContext = json;`?

Comment: your code works fine but i can not under stand why you use friends while class name is friend

Comment: You specify the name of the variable on the `RootObject` class which contains all the items, which is the list which is named "friends". Take a look here for a good introduction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207023(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Bindingacontroltoacollectionofobjects