# getting autocomplete box with possible places (addresses) Windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, autocomplete, location

since a few days i search the web for a solution. 
what i want to achive is a autocomplete searchbox, which at the end gives me the longitude and latidue of the searched adress or place.

So [here](http://blog.tarams.com/index.php/2013/location-autocomplete-and-bing-maps-in-windowsphone/#sthash.VJprtvp0.vzApqDTR.dpbs) i have exactly what i need, the problem is, that the images are gone, so i am stuck.

- how do i send the content of the textbox to my locations api url (in my TextChange eventhandler)
- How can i read the json response in the event handler and bind it to my LisBox item?
- and the last point, how do i get longitude and latidue of the selected item, so i can work with that?

here the eventhandler and xaml code

```
private void SearchForTerm(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //??
    }

<TextBox 
      Foreground="Gray" 
      Text="Search Location"
      TextWrapping="Wrap" 
      Margin="0,470,0,0" 
      Height="72" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      AcceptsReturn="True" 
      GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"
      LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" 
      TextChanged="SearchForTerm"
      />

<ListBox x:Name="Suggestion_listbox" 
         Margin="12,65,0,179">

</ListBox>
```

thx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use AutoCompleteBox from WPToolkit and that will be very convenient and easy to use.There are plenty of tutorial about that and here is the [one](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Auto_Complete_Box_in_Windows_Phone).

If you want to get results after each text changed event, then you can call to that webservice using WebClient with that changed text.I am not sure about that location api but here is an example to get the current weather information from OpenWeatherMapAPI. You can use that in your case too to get data.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted+=wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+location +"&units=metric",UriKind.Absolute));
```

And after getting response from web service, you can deserialize JSON response using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) And to map the json response to c# classes you can use this web tool- [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) Here is the DownloadStringCompleted event handler of my example.

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
     {
            WeatherData weatherDt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherData>(e.Result);
     }
}
```

Here WeatherData is the Root Object of that Json response. and you can map the json response to WeatherData object using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Result);

For DataBinding to list please see the solution of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431149/data-binding-in-listbox-on-windows-phone-8).

And to get the selected item as an object you can use a Tap event handler.

```
 private void Suggestion_listbox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
 {
        ListBox list = sender as ListBox;
        ClassName obj = list.SelectedItem as ClassName;
 }
```

Comment: thank you, i think this will work. but i have one more question: Does the line:
 RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result); always has to be the RootObject? because i need the address and it is (how to say) "deeper" in the json response.. sry for my english :)

Comment: Every RootObject must contain the reference objects to the entire JSON response and their corresponding classes. Like if i want to get the maximum temperature from my example's api i can get that from weatherDt.main.temp_max where weatherDt is my RootObject. You can access properties of an object like that to get the location data from RootObject or just simply bind the rootObject to the list and get data from that using data binding technique.