# parsing json data in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I am making a Windows Phone app in which I have to parse JSON data. The data structure of the JSON data is

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>>
```

I want to display the data in the data structure by binding with UI controls. I know ListBox can be used here. Can you show me the code to bind the data in the data structure with the UI controls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data binding in ListBox on Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431149/data-binding-in-listbox-on-windows-phone-8)

Comment: The ans of the question is how to bind any data to listbox. But I want to display the data in the data structure I have written.

Comment: Have you looked at [Newtonsoft.JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)? This will parse your JSON and convert to a .NET object. Then you just follow the instructions in the linked question.

Comment: Yes I have. I know how to parse json data into C# objects and then display            it using ListBox. But in my case here the data structure is little bit complex. So I am not able to display the data using ListBox. Here is the link of the c# classes after using json2csharp.com : https://goo.gl/6VIq4g